# Cron status is always missed in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have set a cron in magento 1.9. Cron scheduled as per on time but never execute and complete with status of **missed**

Here's the cron configuration in system->configuration->Advanced->System
[image]

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <meanbee_vipmembership>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>meanbee_vipmembership/observer::checkVIPMemberships</model>
            </run>
        </meanbee_vipmembership>
    </jobs>
  </crontab>
</config>
```

Why this is happening please suggest me right answer.

Comment: did you set up cron jobs in server  ?

Comment: Yes, I did it .

Comment: okay make sure cron job is working perfectly by installing Aoe scheduler extension or in some other way......

Comment: Yes I am using Aoe scheduler but as I can see that some of cron is running successfully but mine is not.

Comment: you can include those information in question , also check log errors once....